# Generate an error log from Powershell

Tags: script, powershell

I created a script to assist in mass editing permissions inside an extensive folder structure, based off a list inside a CSV file. The script works as expected, but for several of the folders, I know the script should fail and throw an error because the folder doesn't exist. However, I'm getting no output from the script, aside from a running list I have to notify me of the current folder. I've attempted Try-Catch, but the script stops processing on the first error and I'm not sure how to engineer Catch to keep the script going. What's the best way to keep the script processing, but output errors I know exist to a file so I can later review them?

For example, when the code runs, it should work on Folders 1-3. If folder 2 doesn't exists, Powershell used to throw an error with the path it couldn't find and would continue on. I would like that error in a file to parse later since some folders don't follow the structure modified by this script.

```
$CSV=Import-Csv "C:\ProjectList.csv"

ForEach ($Entry in $CSV)

{

$ProjectNumber = $Entry.Projects
$Project = "$ProjectMain\$ProjectNumber"

Write-Host $Project  #Writes out current project being processed

#sddl defines

$sddlProject = 'D:PAI(D;CI;DCLCSDWDWO;;;DU)(D;CI;DCLCSDWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-513)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIIO;FA;;;CO)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;FA;;;DA)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;DU)(A;OICI;FA;;;S-1-5-21-512)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;S-1-5-21-513)'

$sddlRootFolders = 'D:PAI(D;;SDWDWO;;;DU)(D;;SDWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-513)(A;OICIIO;FA;;;CO)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;FA;;;DA)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;DU)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICI;FA;;;S-1-5-21-512)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-513)'

$sddlCommon = 'D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIIOID;FA;;;CO)(A;OICIID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIID;FA;;;DA)(A;OICIID;0x1301bf;;;DU)(A;OICIIOID;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-512)(A;OICIID;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-513)'

$sddlMGMT = 'D:PAI(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-1501)(A;OICIIO;FA;;;CO)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-12461)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-12462)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-12463)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-12464)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-12465)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-12466)(A;OICI;FA;;;DA)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-1486)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-1487)(A;OICI;FA;;;S-1-5-21-512)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)'


$sddlFiles = 'D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;DA)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;DU)(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-512)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-513)'


#Apply ACL to main folder

$securityDescriptor = Get-Acl -Path $Project
$securityDescriptor.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($sddlProject)
Set-Acl -Path $Project -AclObject $securityDescriptor 


#Apply ACL to the top tier folders

$ProjectSub = $Project + "\Folder1"
$securityDescriptor = Get-Acl -Path $ProjectSub
$securityDescriptor.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($sddlRootFolders)
Set-Acl -Path $ProjectSub -AclObject $securityDescriptor

$ProjectSub = $Project + "\Folder2"
$securityDescriptor = Get-Acl -Path $ProjectSub
$securityDescriptor.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($sddlRootFolders)
Set-Acl -Path $ProjectSub -AclObject $securityDescriptor

$ProjectSub = $Project + "\Folder3"
$securityDescriptor = Get-Acl -Path $ProjectSub
$securityDescriptor.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($sddlRootFolders)
Set-Acl -Path $ProjectSub -AclObject $securityDescriptor

#Apply ACL to MGMT folders

$ProjectSub = $Project + "\Folder9"

$ProjectDiscSub = $ProjectSub + "\MGMT"
$securityDescriptor = Get-Acl -Path $ProjectDiscSub 
$securityDescriptor.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($sddlMGMT)
Set-Acl -Path $ProjectDiscSub -AclObject $securityDescriptor

#Apply ACL to MGMT inside folders

$ProjectDiscSub = $Project + "\Folder1\MGMT"
$securityDescriptor = Get-Acl -Path $ProjectDiscSub
$sddlMGMTSub = 'D:PAI(D;;SDWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-12471)(D;;SDWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-1497)(A;OICIIO;FA;;;CO)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-12471)(A;OICI;FA;;;DA)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-1497)(A;OICI;FA;;;S-1-5-21-512)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)'
$securityDescriptor.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($sddlMGMTSub)
Set-Acl -Path $ProjectDiscSub -AclObject $securityDescriptor

$ProjectDiscSub = $Project + "\Folder3\MGMT"
$securityDescriptor = Get-Acl -Path $ProjectDiscSub
$sddlMGMTSub = 'D:PAI(D;;SDWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-12469)(D;;SDWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-1501)(A;OICIIO;FA;;;CO)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-12469)(A;OICI;FA;;;DA)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;S-1-5-21-1501)(A;OICI;FA;;;S-1-5-21-512)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)'
$securityDescriptor.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($sddlMGMTSub)
Set-Acl -Path $ProjectDiscSub -AclObject $securityDescriptor

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several strategies for handling errors like that.

The first is to add an `-ErrorAction` parameter to the command that may fail.

The second is to wrap the command in try/catch:

```
$ProjectSub = $Project + "\Folder2"
$securityDescriptor = Get-Acl -Path $ProjectSub
$securityDescriptor.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($sddlRootFolders)
try {
    Set-Acl -Path $ProjectSub -AclObject $securityDescriptor
} catch {
    "Poo"
}
"Do more"
```

Note that in both cases, you still get the standard error messages but that execution continues. In the former case, execution moves to the next line. In the try/catch, the catch is executed (prints "Poo") then the next line ("Do More"). You only really need the try/catch if you want to do something only on failure such as save some details to a different file for later processing.

In your case, assuming that the processing list is not too big, you could create a custom object in the catch to accumulate non-existent file details into a variable. Then at the end of the script, write the variable to a file. Just watch out for the variable getting too big. I've had scripts with 10's of thousands of results use up rather large amounts of memory!

Comment: I thougth of that, but the processing list is rather large. The script shown is drastically cut down for ease of reading and when I ran it on one structure, it ran for 50 minutes. i need to just dump the error and move on. -ErrorAction moves on, but it doesn't dump the error out into a file for me.

Comment: Ah, got interrupted and 5 minute timer got me. When i did the Try/Catch, I was trying to do it on more than just the commands. I'll try that on each command itself and have it append to a file and see if that gets me what I need.

Comment: I can't Vote Up since i don't have the reputation yet, but wanted to say thank you, Julian. The Try/Catch pet command works. I have the failure outputting the path, so the error file fills with a path of failed projects and/or folders, depending on the variable I use. It's enough to accomplish what I need.

Comment: No problem @Meckron, I think you should be able to accept this as the correct answer tomorrow (I seem to remember you have to wait 24hrs?) That will give me some extra points too, always welcome :)